# What kind of alternate history would lead to modern China being a federal constitutional monarchy?

Tags: alternate-history, politics, civilization, history

I'm contemplating writing a fiction set in modern China in an alternate universe. I have thought about how it would look like, but I need a plausible alternate history that could lead to such result.

**Setting**

It was the year 2020 AD. China was a federal constitutional monarchy in the alternate universe. Unlike most federations in our universe, its different federal units had vastly different nature, ranging from kingdoms to special administrative regions. In total, it consisted of *3 kingdoms, 2 khanates, 2 republics, 4 special administrative regions and 1 capital district*.

**Kingdoms**

The three kingdoms were located in North China Plain, Yangtze Plain and Sichuan Plain respectively. Among them the kingdom in North China Plain was the most politically powerful. They together made up more than 60% of population. Their heads of federal unit were called *Kings/Queens* and were hereditary positions. The royal family of the kingdom in North China Plain had a mixed origin of Han and non-Han, while the other two royal families were Han for the most part.

**Khanates**

The two khanates were located in Mongolian-Manchurian steppe and Tarim Basin respectively. Their heads of federal unit were called *Khans* and were hereditary positions. Both khan families had a mixed origin of Han and non-Han.

**Republics**

The two republics were both located in southern China. Their heads of federal unit were called *Chief Ministers*, who were also their heads of government and were elected positions.

**Special administrative regions**

Among the four special administrative regions, two of them were located in Pearl River Delta and other two in Yangtze River delta. Their heads of federal unit were called *Chief Executives*, who were also their heads of government and were elected positions.

**Capital district**

The capital district was the oldest and the central part of Beijing. It was also called the *Old Beijing* by the locals. Its head of federal unit was called the *Mayor*, who was also its heads of government and was elected positions.

**Emperor/Empress of China**

The head of state on federal level was called the *Emperor/Empress of China*. **Whoever succeeded to the throne of the kingdom in North China Plain was automatically crowned the Emperor/Empress of China.** However, in case the kingdom in North China Plain was in regency, the Kings/Queens of the other two kingdoms could act as regents for the Emperor/Empress of China.

Being the monarch in a constitutional monarchy, the Emperor/Empress was largely a ceremonial role and had limited political power. Their most significant power was to appoint the *Prime Minister*, who was the head of government on federal level.

**Republic of Formosa**

A.K.A Taiwan. The Republic of Formosa was not under the sovereignty of China, but it recognized the Emperor/Empress of China as its head of state. This was similar to how Canada and Australia recognize the UK monarch as their head of state in our universe.

**Question:**

What plausible alternate history would lead to the China described above?

Comment: I think a series of events might be in order rather than a single historical change. One of those changes being obviously at what we know as the tail end of the Mongolian ?Song? Dynasty (I seem to recall that the descendants of Genghis Khan split the empire into 4 entities). Somehow one/two remain and these shift and morph into your khanates over the centuries. Then exposure to a slightly altered western influence results in your admin regions etc

Comment: The self-titled People's Republic is an empire. It would be helpful if the question listed the substantive differences between the proposed structure and the actual real-life Chinese Empire. No, words do not count; words are not magic. Calling Mr. Jinping Xi an Emperor and Prime Minister instead of his actual titles of President, General Secretary and Military Chairman doesn't change *anything* in real life. Calling Mr. Taifeng Shi the Khan of Inner Mongolia instead of his actual titles of Lord and Master (自治区委书记 and 人大常委会主任 in Mandarin Chinese) is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. You're effectively asking us to write the history of your world for you.

Answer (score 5):

I might have a partial vision of history, but I have the impression that the concept of constitutional monarchy has arisen originally in countries which had somehow contacts with the Greek concept of democracy, basically Europe, and even there for a long time it has been only England to have some sort of limitations on what the ruler could do with its Magna Charta, before it became a sort of widespread achievement. Between that England and the Greek civilization there is a large gap of fight between monarchs and their subordinates on who should hold the power.

Based on this I think you should have prolonged contacts between the Greek poleis and China, so that Greek culture can somehow permanently influence the Chines one, and after that China should follow a path similar to Germany to become a federation of smaller and bigger states under the ruling of a single monarch.

Probably the only way to achieve this is to have first an established trade relationship between China and Greece, followed by Alexander the Great successfully invading the North of India until reaching what is today China and keeping his power in place for a decent time through a durable empire, so that the states sprouting after the end of the empire he founded would embed part of the Greek cultural heritage.

Comment: European culture contributed. But outside Europe, Morocco, Jordan, Kuwait, Bahrain, Malaysia and Japan have formed constitutional monarchies. Thailand likes to be called a constitutional monarchy, but lack of constitution since 2014 says it is not.  The presence of an actual constitution determines it. A legal basis, or  substitute for the absolute  (also legal) power of the monarch. In modern times, it became a political choice, rather than foreign (mainly British) influence. It can weaken a monarch, without having the monarch himself loosing face.

Answer (score 4):

**It was attempted for a few years.. it failed**

First some documentation/context

Once, between 1908 and 1911 they tried it. The Qing dynasty attempted to hold on to power, by doing concessions: introducing a constitutional system and put other reforms, to please the revolutionaries.  China might have become a constitutional monarchy, with the last emperor and his political elite in power. Intentions were clear.. but the Qing never succeeded in actually founding a constitutional monarchy. This was - among other things - because the Qing-dynasty was Manchurian and not Han, which is the majority of the population. The 1908 proposal was not acceptable to revolutionaries, nor for the Han.. nor for the Qing elite..

The Chinese Republic was founded in 1912 and briefly overthrown a few years later, in 1915-1916 by Yuan Shikai, the architect of the Qing reforms. A war broke out and Shikai lost. And the child emperor Puyi now became emperor-in-name only, isolated in the Forbidden City.

Puyi would become the *very* last emperor of China. When China was invaded by Japan in WW-II, Puyi collaborated with Japan. After the war, he was put to prison for 10 years.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_the_Constitution_(1908)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_Shikai

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puyi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1911_Revolution

As for the opening question, I see two roads rooted in history,

**Chinese constitutional monarchy from within**

You could say the Qing lost already with the Boxer uprisings in 1895.. or in 1912, or in 1916. Or definitely, in 1946. What would have been needed to change the above events ? In 1915-1916, the Qing attempted one more time to regain power, lead by Yuan Shikai, who inspired the reforms.

*Suppose* Yuan Shikai would have won the war in 1916 and prevent the communist and nationalist warlords from taking over ? Maybe he could have restored order and  proceeded the constitutional reforms, with himself as emperor.

.. or *suppose* the 1908 reform would have been accepted in the first place, and revolution was avoided.. the successor Puyi was 2 years old, enough time to park the imperial elite and experiment with a constitutional monarchy, with the emperor getting used to ceremonial functions at a very young age.

**Chinese constitutional monarchy instated from the outside**

*Suppose* Britain would have imposed colonial rule over larger parts of China, in that case, decolonization negotiations could have resulted in an Anglo-Saxon model of constitutional rule, at least within these former British territories.

..or *suppose*, Puyi would not have committed treason during WW-II ? What if the Americans would had intervened, to help nationalist Chiang Kai-shek and prevent communist regime ? A constitutional monarch Puyi, head of state *in name*.. and a puppet as prime minister..

..or *suppose* Japan would have won WO-II.. same procedure as the Americans, they could have installed their constitution (which was the plan in 1908 anyway) and their man Puyi as constitutional emperor of China.

**Federal**

In the above scenarios, I avoided "Federal". Until far in the 20th century, China was divided. The strong central government in China pacified that situation for centuries. When the empire was compromised, war broke out. Then, the communists restored one China again, with central rule. A federation assumes relative independence of participants, which would result in separatism everywhere, like it played out in Yugoslavia, after Tito died in 1980. It was not viable as a single state.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible alternatives that could have radically changed modern China. Go back to the Mongol invasion and change that.

1. If the Khans had not conquered the different kingdoms in China. That would have left a far different political landscape, one that was fragmented and could have fragmented further.
2. If the Khans had decided to go with a "scorched earth" policy returning the conquered lands into pastures for horses. A greatly reduced population would have resulted which would not have supported a unified empire.

Comment: Small kingdoms happen when populations are dispersed or when the landscape prevents easy trade (see mountains). Empires happen when one group is able to conquer a lot of territory and hold it. That requires a minimum population level and ease of trade/movement of armed forces. The Incan empire required building roads in order to maintain. Chaco had a major road network. When the population is lacking or it is hard to move troops, areas break off or never get conquered. Thus, a lot of small kingdoms happen around empires. See Nepal, etc.

Comment: In the western world, democracies appear when the lower class is successful in overthrowing the king.

Answer (score 0):

**Douglas MacArthur’s Success**

From Wikipedia:

> When North Korea invaded South Korea in June 1950, starting the Korean War, MacArthur was designated commander of the
> United Nations forces defending South Korea. He conceived and executed the amphibious assault at Inchon on 15 September
> 1950, for which he was hailed as a military genius.

At this point, reality turned on fate:

> However, when he followed up his victory with a full-scale invasion of North Korea on Truman's orders, China intervened in the
> war and inflicted a series of defeats, compelling him to withdraw from North Korea. By April 1951, the military situation had
> stabilized, but MacArthur continued to publicly criticize his superiors and attempt to escalate the conflict, leading Truman to relieve MacArthur of his commands.

Instead of MacArthur losing, or insubordination, or something, MacArthur managed to press on into China, expanding the Korean War into the US-China War for which the US emerged victorious.

One of the concessions was that China adopt a federal constitutionally based society, which the victors assisted China in adopting. The eventual form became a monarchy, primarily from the Chinese own participation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the Korean war seemed to be too recent to have led to the desired result. By 1950, the last dynasty of China was long gone, and there was not a single khanate on the map.

Comment: @user141240: Words are not magic. What's a "khanate" really other than a state, of whatever variety, which calls its head of state a khan? Just call Mr. Taifeng Shi a "khan" of Inner Mongolia; he is the Big Kahuna of the province anyway. Quiz: his actual titles are 自治区委书记 and 人大常委会主任; are you sure than neither of those beautiful phrases means "khan"?

Comment: I don't care how much of a strategic genius MacArthur is: China's too big to conquer, and Mao isn't going to surrender in response to anything less.